# Scaling of mass density

Tags: classical-mechanics, mass, geometry, density

Let distances scale as $L'=kL$, $k$ is the scaling factor. Then spherical volume will scale as $V'=k^3 V$. 
Say, the sphere is filled with mass with constant density. If we scale the model with scaling factor $k$, what is the scaling law for the density?

Comment: When you scale up the model, are you changing the mass? Constant density implies that the density will not change regardless of the size of the object. So perhaps I'm not sure what you're asking. My point is that if you have a half cup of water, and then you add another cup, the density is still that of water, regardless of how much you add ("scale up").

Comment: I meant when you scale the size, how would the mass change with that. It is confusing, because the mass depends on the volume and the density, and the density is [$kg/m^3$]... Is it even possible that density can be scaled down when the size is scaled down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a constant density $\rho$, so we know that either model will have the same mass density. It's like the fact that a cup of water has the same density as a gallon of water -- when density is constant, mass and volume will change correspondingly to maintain said density.

Let's look at this to figure out the new mass. First note that since
$$ \rho = \frac{M}{V},$$
we see
$$ M = \rho V.$$
In the old model, we have
$$ M = \rho V.$$
In the new model we have
$$ M' = \rho V' = \rho (k^3 V). $$
Therefore, simply dividing the two, we find that
$$\frac{M'}{M} = \frac{\rho k^3V}{\rho V} = k^3. $$
So we conclude that the $M' = k^3 M$, which means the new mass is $k^3$ times greater than the old model's mass.

Check:
For the new model
$$ \rho = \frac{M'}{V'} = \frac{k^3 M}{k^3 V} = \frac{M}{V}$$
so the density is the same in both models as we imposed.